# Compiling to a binary from source

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using WKHTMLTOPDF on a 64-bit Linux server and I'm running into problems with the version.

Seen here: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

There's slim pickins when it comes to pre-compiled binaries. I started with version 0.9.9 which has a few bugs. I upgraded to 0.11.0 RC 1 to find a slew of new problems, namely the following:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=730

I think 0.10 RC 2 would work, and the thread above suggests compiling from the source has a fix for the error I'm getting, but I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone explain how I can create a static binary myself, or would anyone be willing to create and post one for the countless people waiting for this fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pre-compiled static binary for 64-bit 0.10 RC 2:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2&can=1&q=

[Here's a list of all the binaries you can have](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list?can=1&q=wkhtmltopdf%20amd64%20static&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) (note that this one is put down as Deprecated, but I used it for a previous project for very similar reasons, and it worked perfectly).

Comment: Ho damn, I just needed to change the dropdown! Thank you thank you.